# Tabbed fragments list views are not updated when related data is changed in other fragment

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, tabs

I used a TabLayout for a tabbed view in my app. I added three List fragments - one for each tab.

The content of either of the fragments is supposed to be changed (and the list views have to be updated) when new record is added/removed from any of the fragments.

But after I modify some data and swiped to the next tab the list view is not updated and retained the old data.

I created an interface that is implemented in all of the ListFragments as follows:

```
public interface UpdatableFragment {

    void updateContent();
}

public class LogFragment implements  UpdatableFragment{
...
    @Override
    public void updateContent() {

        Activity activity = getActivity();

        if (isAdded() && activity != null) {

            getLoaderManager().restartLoader(LOG_LIST_LOADER, null, this);
        }
    }
...
}
```

And I call the method in the MainActivity tab select listener

```
 tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

                if(adapter != null){

                    int position = viewPager.getCurrentItem();

                    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
                    viewPager.setCurrentItem(position);

                    Fragment tabbedFragment =  adapter.getItem(viewPager.getCurrentItem());

                    if(tabbedFragment instanceof UpdatableFragment){

                        ((UpdatableFragment) tabbedFragment).updateContent();                               
                    }
                }
            }
```

But the condition `if (isAdded() && activity != null)`  in updateContent() method sometimes returns false because activity becomes null. On other times, it returns the MainActivity instance and the loader restarts.

Why is this inconsistent behavior happening and how can I make the ListFragments always show fresh content when their corresponding tabs are selected?

EDIT
adding the fragment pager code

```
class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
        super(manager);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {

        return mFragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragmentList.size();
    }

    public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
        mFragmentList.add(fragment);
        mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `getItem(int position)` method does not return a reference to the `Fragment` currently in that position of your `ViewPager`. The `getItem()` method is used in the `PagerAdapter` when it calls `instantiateItem()` to create your views/fragments, so when you call `getItem(int position)` it's creating a brand new `Fragment` for you, and this is not added/attached to your `Activity` (causing the false/null in your if check). If you look into the code for `FragmentPagerAdapter.instantiateItem()` you can see where it calls `getItem()` and then adds the `Fragment` with the `FragmentManager`.

One way to get around this is to cache your `Fragment` references in your `FragmentPagerAdapter` (do this by caching the `Fragment` returned by `instantiateItem()` and remove the references in `adapter.destroyItem()`), or calling `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` to re-create your views with the updated data.

**UPDATE:**

You want to add something like this to your `FragmentPagerAdapter`:

```
public class Adapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

  private SparseArray<Fragment> fragmentCache = new SparseArray<>();

  @Override public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
    Fragment fragment = (Fragment) super.instantiateItem(container, position);
    fragmentCache.put(position, fragment);
    return fragment;
  }

  @Override public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
    fragmentCache.remove(position);
    super.destroyItem(container, position, object);
  }
  // other code....
}
```

You can then get references to all the fragments currently in your adapter from the `fragmentCache`, and then you can call your `updateContent` method on them.

Comment: thank you Alex, I updated my question to add the pagerAdapter  part. Please comment on the actual code I used.

Comment: I think I cached them (in myFragmentList)  when creating the fragments in `addFragment()` and used the 'cache' to get fragment items out of it. What is the SparseArray implementation different in terms of caching the original fragments?

Comment: Alex, and also the behavior is inconsistent. Sometimes it works. Only on some occasions is it fails to work. If new instances of the fragments were always get returned, then it wouldn't work for some tab swipes.

Comment: Alex, one more thing: I compared the fragment object ids that are returned from getItem(int position) with that of the original fragment instances existing in the adapter. They are the same. So I am actually invoking the methods of the original fragments.

Comment: In what situations is the inconsistency happening? When scrolling through the `ViewPager`? When selecting a `Tab`? Screen rotation?, etc. I've made a small test project using the code you've supplied and updating a `TextView` in a test fragment, and nothing looks wrong to me.

Comment: Ok I think I know the issue you're seeing here. By default a `ViewPager` only attaches/adds the current page, and one page on either side of the current page (so 3 total). You're trying to update all the fragments in the view pager (of which only up to 3 of them are currently attached/added). You need a removal mechanism for your caching like in my edit so that you're not attempting to update fragments outside what's currently attached in the `ViewPager`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106736/discussion-between-alex-townsend-and-bere).